# Calculate ratio of two parameters using Pyomo, Python

Tags: python-3.x, modeling, pyomo, mixed-integer-programming

I have 2 parameters such as Demand and Capacity:
I have modeled these as follows:

```
model.Dmem=Param(model.nf,within=NonNegativeIntegers, initialize=1)
model.Cmem=Param(model.ns, within=NonNegativeIntegers, initialize=5)
```

I want to calculate the ratio of these two parameters.
I did this by dividing the parameters above as:

`model.ame=expr(model.Cmem/model.Dmem)`

But the error I am receiving is:

**TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'IndexedParam' and 'IndexedParam'**

Please help.

Regards

Comment: Is model.ame another Pyomo parameter? How do you want to use the expression you define in your question?

Comment: @gmavrom
thanks for reaching out. Actually, I have two resources, demanded and total capacity, and I want to calculate the ratio of used resources by dividing the total capacity by demand. I am not sure how to do it correctly. Please guide.

Comment: So you currently have `Dmem[nf]` and `Cmem[ns]`. How is `amem` defined? Is it that `amem[nf, ns]` and is equal to the ratio between the other parameters for all pairs of `(nf, ns)`?

Comment: Dear @gmavrom Yes, model.ame will be the ratio.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correct and, indeed, `model.ame` is a Pyomo parameter, you can initialize it doing the following:

```
def ame_rule(model, ns, nf):
    return model.Cmem[ns]/model.Dmem[nf]

model.ame=Param(model.ns, model.nf, initialize=ame_rule)
```

That way Pyomo will construct your `ame` parameter by calling the `ame_rule` function for every pair of `ns` and `nf`.

Comment: Thank you so much dear @gmavrom,

when I multiply the **model.ame** with another parameter, I get errors such as:

_name 'ub' is not defined. Did you mean: 'u'?_

Actually I have this constraint, **Summation[(Binary Var Fi)*(Param Dmem)<=(ratio param model.ame)*(Param Cmem)]**.    
I am defining the constraints as follows:
`for u in model.ns:
    model.constraints.add(sum(model.fiubu[ub, u] * model.Dmem[ub] for ub in model.nf<= model.ame[u, ub]for u in model.ns for ub in model.nf * model.Cmem[u]))`